# How to create full featured snippets in Dreamwever CS6?

Tags: dreamweaver, code-snippets

How to create full featured  snippets in `Dreamwever CS6` ?
(similar to creating snippets in Sublime `Text 2` - just like in this video: [Here](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/your-first-snippet/)). I want to create a snippet with two or more places where i can insert a code (and switching between those places with tab). Is it doable in `Dreamweaver` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver does not support parameterizable snippets, you cannot hit tab and the cursor is moved to the next parameter in your code chunk. Once a snippet is added to the page, it is editable like all other text.

The only way to get anything like a parameterizable snippet would be to create a Dreamweaver extension user interface (perhaps an Object or Command). Perhaps the following article can help with that: http://www.dwfaq.com/tutorials/extensions/simple_object.asp